# How to handle large Emailing queue and delivery with AWS SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

We are developing an app. that need to handle large email queues. We have planned to store emails in a SQS queue and use SES to send emails. but a bit confused on how to actually handle the queue and process queue. should I use cronjob to regularly read the SQS queue and send emails? What would be the best way to actually trigger the script that will be emailing from our app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using SQS with SES is a great way to handle this. If something goes wrong while emailing the request will still be on the queue and will be processed next time around.

I just use a cron job that starts my queue processing/email sending job once an hour. The job runs for an hour as a simple loop:

```
while i've been running < 1 hour:
    if there's a message in the queue:
        process the message
        delete the message from the queue
```

I set the `WaitTimeSeconds` parameter to the maximum (20 seconds) so that the check for a new message will wait a while for a new message if necessary so that the job isn't hitting AWS every few milliseconds. Otherwise, I could put a `sleep` statement of some kind in the loop.

The reason I run for just an hour is that the job might encounter some error that kills it, or have a memory leak, or some other unanticipated problem. This way any queued email requests will still get handled the next time the job is started.

If you want, you can start the job every fifteen minutes so you'll always have four worker processes handling queue requests. If one of them dies for some reason, you'll still be processing with the other three.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. So if we check queue for msg every hour. we should be ready to accept that email delivery could be 1 hour late?

Comment: Yes, if you only check hourly. But in this example, you are checking all the time. As soon as a check fails due to timeout, you check again. The only way you could have a delay is if your program unexpectedly crashes.

Comment: @CharlesEngelke for your solution, are you stuffing the whole email in as the SQS message content, or is there just a reference to the message in SQS? Have you noticed any performance issues adding messages to the queue? Batched messages seem to be limited to [64k in total](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-batch-api.html), so this doesn't seem like an option.

Comment: I do put the whole email in the message content, without attachments. If I need to send anything big, I put that object in S3 and just have a link to it in the email. One "trick" I use is for messages to a big list. I queue a single message referencing the list, and then the handler for the message just creates queue entries for each individual message. The queue handlers for those actually send the emails.